# Compilation error when attempting to define text in a `pic` command

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

The following MWE is an excerpt from the signature picture heading Part III of `Tantau's TikZ & PGF Manual Version 3.0.1a, page 118`. For unknown reasons, if the line `pic [draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}` specifies some text to be inserted, here for example `"$\alpha$"`, compilation error `! Missing \endcsname inserted.` occurs. Why?

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 18 Oct 2017
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3,0) coordinate (A)
-- (0,1) coordinate (B)
-- (1,2) coordinate (C)
pic [draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}
%  pic ["$\alpha$",draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C}
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm just guessing but can you move `"$\alpha$"` to the end of the options ? Or you have to load `quotes` library too.

Comment: At the first occurrence of `pic`(page 46 of the manual) there is "Karl needs to load the `angles` library and the `quotes` for the following examples". So `quotes` is missing, as @percusse said.

Comment: Alternatively `pic text=$\alpha$` could be used.

Comment: @percusse @campa@ esdd  I had tried all permutations of which order to use for the `pic` parameters before I asked the question, but loading `quotes` is the answer, as is putting `pic [text="...", ... ]`.
Not sure how to mark your contributions as the answer, but they are!

Comment: @campa First come first serve, care to add an answer?

Comment: @percusse Honestly, without your comment I wouldn't have thought of `quotes` (I know basically nothing of `tikz`). So you are the first `;-)`

Comment: Whoever it is going to be, it will be my pleasure to award the TICK!

Comment: @campa I really don't have any TeX access so no problem at all. Please go ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order is not really important but in order to use the quotes one must load the `quotes` library, as the `tikz` manual (admittedly, a wee bit hidden) suggests

> Karl needs to load the `angles` library and the `quotes` for the following
>   examples

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3,0) coordinate (A)
-- (0,1) coordinate (B)
-- (1,2) coordinate (C)
pic ["$\alpha$",draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As esdd pointed out one can achieve the result without loading `quotes` by using the `pic text` key

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (3,0) coordinate (A)
-- (0,1) coordinate (B)
-- (1,2) coordinate (C)
pic [pic text=$\alpha$,draw, fill=yellow]{angle= A--B--C} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```